# RichFaces is undefined error

Tags: richfaces

I am migrating my application to higher Spring version from 4.0.5 to 4.3.0 , during which Rich-faces got migrated from 4.3.5 to 4.5.2

I am facing 'RichFaces' is undefined when ever i load the login page. Code snippets and further details have been attached. Please help!
newLogin.Jsp

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
    <jsp:forward page="/pages/login/loginMain.jsf"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

loginMain.xhtml

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  xmlns:cls="http://emia.com/emia/ui"
  xmlns:cat360="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">
  <ui:composition template="/templates/login/loginTemplate.xhtml">
 
<h:commandButton type="submit" id="login" onclick="loginTest(); return false;" value="login" styleClass="submitButton" />
 
<a4j:commandLink
  styleClass="forgetPass" value="Forgot Password?">
  <rich:componentControl target="forgotPasswordPopup"
  operation="show" event="click" />
  </a4j:commandLink>
```

Comment: I have some screenshots to attach but unable to do here not sure how to attach the screen shots.

Before migrating the path was referring to 

/javax.faces.resource/richfaces.js.jsf
/javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.jsf
/rfRes/skinning.ecss.jsf?db=eAHjW!XqPQAE!QKS

After migration the path is :

/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/richfaces.js
/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/jquery.js
/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/skinning.ecss?db=eAG7dPvZfwAIqAOT

Comment: Do you have any filters in web.xml? They may be redirecting the resources somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks ...

<web-app id="richfaces-showcase" version="2.5"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.richfaces.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/org.richfaces.resources/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: That looks ok (but next time edit you question), does Spring have some resource-related settings? I'm not familiar with it.